# How to apply MATLAB addpath to non static string?

Tags: matlab

```
dir1 = '/tmp1';
dir2 = '/tmp2'
```

If we do the following

```
addpath [dir1 dir2];
```

MATLAB takes '[dir1 dir2]' as the path name to add. We can do the following

```
eval(sprintf(...
  'addpath %s;', ...
  [dir1  dir2]));
```

I was wondering if there is any better way. Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general issue that you are having is that MATLAB has two ways of calling commands. The first does not use an explicit function call `function()` but rather just multiple inputs on the command line separated by a space:

```
addpath directory1 directory2
```

As you know this will add both `directory1` and `directory2` to the path.

What is happening here is that MATLAB converts all of the inputs to strings implicitly and passes them to the `addpath` function. The explicit equivalent is

```
addpath('directory1', 'directory2')
```

As you can see, internally MATLAB calls `addpath` like a normal function with input parameters, and as such you can pass it variables rather than string literals:

```
dir1 = 'directory1';
dir2 = 'directory2';

addpath(dir1, dir2);
```

This is why you are seeing an issue with:

```
addpath [dir1 dir2]
```

Because, as written, `[dir1 dir2]` is convert to a string (implicitly) since it was passed using the `function parameter1 parameter2` syntax rather than the explicit function syntax.

Also, be careful because `[dir1, dir2]` doesn't do what you *think* it does. What it actually does it *appends* the strings `dir1` and `dir2` and would result in:

```
[dir1, dir2]
/tmp1/tmp2
```

If that *is* what you expect, then use `fullfile` rather than basic horizontal concatenation to ensure you have the proper file separators, etc.

```
addpath(fullfile(dir1, dir2));
```

You will actually see the implicit syntax in many MATLAB functions that accept only strings as input parameters. It is important to know, though, that you can *always* use the explicit function call `function()` instead to pass input strings which may be stored in variables.

Answer (score 3):

A very simple way to achieve what you want is to call:

```
addpath(fullfile(dir1,dir2));
```

Fullfile will take care of adjusting the string to be a proper folder name (under both Windows and Unix) as in:

```
fullfile('foo','bar') % returns foo/bar
fullfile('foo/','bar') % returns foo/bar
```

To add files recursively just do:

```
pathsToAdd = genpath(fullfile(dir1,dir2));
addpath(pathsToAdd);
```